# SQL Reporting Services no puede conectar a instancia SQL local

Tags: sql-server

El problema es el siguiente. Tengo una instancia local de SQL Server (2019 express) y estoy intentando configurar el Reporting Server. Sin embargo, cuando intento conectar con la instancia para asignarle la BBDD al Reporting Server me sale este error:

> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server.)

Así es como lo tengo todo configurado:

- La instancia de SQL Server tiene un login que corresponde a mi usuario de dominio de Windows.
- La instancia está configurada para admitir conexiones remotas.
- Tengo el protocolo TCP/IP habilitado con el puerto 1433.
- Tengo las canalizaciones con nombre habilitadas. Valor predeterminado "sql\query".
- Tengo reglas habilitadas en el firewall para los puertos 1433 y 1434 para SQL Server y el 80 para Reporting Server.
- He comprobado que el servicio SQL Server está activo.

No entiendo qué me falta... ¿puede ser tema de la canalización predeterminada? Ahora está con el valor sql\query.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si algún otro programa está ocupando esos puertos, skype es uno de los que pueden estar interrumpiendo

Comment: No hay otro que esté escuchando esos puertos. Pero lo extraño es que sql server tampoco. Me aparece sql server browser escuchando al 1434 pero ningún proceso escuchando al 1433 ¿?

Comment: Resuelto, SQL no estaba esuchando al puerto 1433 por alguna razón. Pasos para solucionarlo:

1. Ir al configuration manager.

2. Configuración de red de SQL Server

3. Doble click en TCP/IP

4. Click en direcciones IP

5. En IPALL, en puertos dinámicos TCP modificar el puerto a 1433.